npoco deletemany command not deleting any records
I am using NPoco, in Umbraco, and want to delete multiple records. I have tried this but although it returns the number of records, they are not actually deleted from the database. What am I doing wrong?
public void DeleteArticleViewsById(IEnumerable<int> idList)
{
    using var scope = _scopeProvider.CreateScope();
    
    var x = scope.Database.DeleteMany<ManualViewEntity>()
        .Where(x => x.Pk.In(idList))
        .Execute();

    scope.Complete();

}

ManualViewEntity is defined as
[TableName("ManualView")]
[PrimaryKey(nameof(ManualViewEntity.Pk), AutoIncrement = true)]
[ExplicitColumns]
public class ManualViewEntity
{
    [Ignore] 
    public static string TableName => "ManualView";

    [Column("pk")]
    [PrimaryKeyColumn(AutoIncrement = true, IdentitySeed = 1)]
    public int Pk { get; set; }

    [Column("memberId")]
    public int MemberId { get; set; }

    [Column("articleId")]
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }

    [Column("viewDate")]
    public DateTime ViewDate { get; set; }
}

